# Is there a mapping reduction of E(tm) to OVERLAP(tm)?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, computability

$E_{TM}=$ { < $M$> $|$ $M$ is a TM; $L(M)$=$\varnothing$}

Where $L(M)$ is the language accepted(recognized) by $M$.

$OVERLAP_{TM}=$ {< $M_{1}$,$M_{2}$> $|$ $M_{1}$,$M_{2}$ are TMs;  $L(M_{1})\cap L(M_{2}) \ne \varnothing$}

Is there a mapping reduction of $E_{TM}$ to $OVERLAP_{TM}$ ?

Comment: Yes, and I'm sure you can find it. Try harder.

Comment: Sorry, I revised the question.

Comment: Now there is no reduction since $OVERLAP_{TM}\in RE$ but $E_{TM} \notin RE$. Try to show that.

Comment: I want to try and prove $OVERLAP_{TM}$ is $RE$ (Turing Recognizable). We do this by defining a TM $K$  that will recognize the language: on Input $M_{1} , M_{2}$ simulate them on  words of their input non deterministically and accept if they both accept. (Is this a valid proof!?)